# Interchangeability of integration and differentiation:

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $\mu$ be a measure on $\mathbb{R}^{N}, A$ a subset of
> $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ with $\mu$-measurable properties, I an interval in
> $\mathbb{R}, t_{0} \in I$, and $f: I \times A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
> a function with the following properties:
>
> - For all $t \in I, f(t, \cdot)$ is integrable over A with respect to $\mu$.
> - There exists a neighborhood U of $t_{0}$ such that the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t, x)$ exists for all $t \in
>    U$ and all $x \in A$.
> - There exists a function $g: U \rightarrow[0, \infty)$, integrable with respect to $\mu$ on U, such that for all $t \in U$ and $x \in
>   A,\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(t, x)\right| \leq g(x)$.
>
> Show that the function $F: I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $$
> F(t):=\int \limits_{A} f(t, x) \mathrm{d} \mu(x) $$ is differentiable
> at the point $t_{0}$ with $$ F^{\prime}\left(t_{0}\right)=\int
> \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f\left(t_{o}, x\right) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)
> $$

So far I have considered the following:

With the mean value theorem:
$$
\begin{array}{l}
\frac{f\left(t_{0}+h, x\right)-f\left(t_{0}, x\right)}{h}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(\xi, x) \\
\text { for a } \xi \text { between } t_{0} \text { and } t_{0}+h .
\end{array}
$$

If a function $g: A \rightarrow[0, \infty)$, which is independent of h, with $g(x)=\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(\xi, x)\right|$ fulfils the condition $\left|\frac{f\left(t_{0}+h, x\right)-f\left(t_{0}, x\right)}{h}\right| \leq g(x)$ for all $x \in A$ and since g is integrable, I can apply the theorem on dominated convergence:
$$
\lim \limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \int \limits_{A} \frac{f\left(t_{0}+h, x\right)-f\left(t_{0}, x\right)}{h} \mathrm{~d} \mu(x)=\int \limits_{A} \lim \limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f\left(t_{0}+h, x\right)-f\left(t_{0}, x\right)}{h} \mathrm{~d} \mu(x)
$$
Then follows:
$$
\lim \limits_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{F\left(t_{0}+h\right)-F\left(t_{0}\right)}{h}=\int \limits_{A} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f\left(t_{0}, x\right) \mathrm{d} \mu(x)
$$

Have I thought about this correctly?